# Need to select values from array to dropbox

Tags: php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm really new to this and i'm  trying to get data from an array for a drop down box, here is what I have tried but all that shows in the box is the word array. Anyone able to help?

```
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I will take a look at them articles, do you know how I would then take the data that was chosen and to display on a response page everything  I do it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the array not just print it.

```
<select name="newspaper">
    <?php foreach($newspaper as $index => $item) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $index; ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

You should definitely look up arrays and read more about them.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks for the help I will take a look at them articles, do you know how I would then take the data that was chosen and to display on a response page everything I do it doesn't work